# Incorrect parameter type for function 'LEN()'. Expected Text, received Object

Tags: apex

```
<apex:repeat value="{!desLSt}" var="key">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-bottom">
        <a href="upload.html">
            <div class="img-box">
            <a href="/apex/VendorGalleryUpload?fName={!key}" alt="{!key}">
                <apex:image style="height:172px" url="{!URLFOR($Resource.vigorousity_style, 'vigorousity_style/img/Default-Activity-Slider.jpg')}"  rendered="{!IF(actAttMap[key] =='',true,false)}"/>
                <apex:image style="height:172px" url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!actAttMap[key][0].ID}"  alt="{!key}"  rendered="{!IF(actAttMap[key]!='',true,false)}"/>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="all-side-border">
                <div class="img-box-text">
                <script>
                 // alert('{!key}'.length);
                </script>                                                    
                    <a href="/apex/VendorGalleryUpload?fName={!key}"><strong>{!if(LEN(key)>5,Left(key,5)+'...',key)}</strong></a> // Getting error on this line
                </div>
                <div class="img-box-text">
                    <strong>{!actAttCountMap[key]} photos</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="del-btn" onclick="deleteImage('{!key}')"><I class="fa fa-trash-o"></I></a>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

> "desLSt" is defined as List of String withing Apex.

Comment: Please include the error message in the question body. - [ask]

Comment: desLSt is list of string or list of sobject?

Comment: Can you post your controller code for `desLSt` or confirm the data type of `desLSt` ?

Comment: "desLSt" is defined as List of String withing Apex.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to replicate these results in my developer orgizantion. With the controller code, someone on here might be able to help you more, but without it, I'm unsure this will be resolved.

Ill add the page and controller snippets I used to test this for reference, hopefully you might spot something you did wrong.

## Testing Page

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">

    <apex:repeat value="{!listOfStrings}" var="s">
        <a href="/apex/Somewhere?fName={!s}">
            <strong>{!IF((LEN(s) > 5), LEFT(s, 5) + '...', s)}</strong>
        </a>
        <br />
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

## Testing Controller

```
public class TestController {

    public TestController() {}

    public List<String> listOfStrings {
        get {

            List<String> listOfStrings = new List<String>();

            listOfStrings.add('Something');
            listOfStrings.add('Something Else');
            listOfStrings.add('Some');
            listOfStrings.add('Thing');

            return listOfStrings;

        }
    }

}
```

[image: Correct output (Truncated at 5 chars)]